# A simple menu in a Console Application

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my menu to repeat, so after selecting and doing option 1, it will got back to the menu and ask for another option to be chosen

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        FootballTeams MyCode = new FootballTeams();

        MyCode.ListInit();
        MyCode.DisplayMenu();
        MyCode.AddTeams();
        Console.ReadLine();

        MyCode.ListInit();
        MyCode.DisplayMenu();
        MyCode.DisplayTeams();
        Console.ReadLine();

        MyCode.ListInit();
        MyCode.DisplayMenu();
        MyCode.Delete();
        Console.ReadLine();

        MyCode.ListInit();
        MyCode.DisplayMenu();
        MyCode.TeamSearch();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here are the methods with the contents taken out:

```
class FootballTeams
{


    public FootballTeams(){ }

    List<string> teams;
    public void ListInit()


    public void DisplayMenu()
   {   
    Console.WriteLine("Football Manager");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Football team");
    Console.WriteLine("2. List the Football teams");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Search for a Football team");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a team");
    Console.ReadLine();
    }



    public void AddTeams()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a team to be added: ");
      string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
      if (teams.Count < 10)
      {
       if (userinput != "Colchester")
        {
          teams.Add(userinput);
          foreach (var item in teams)
          Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
         }
        else
          Console.Write("NOT ALLOWED");
         }
       else
         Console.Write("MAXIMUM LIMIT REACHED");
      }


    public void DisplayTeams()
    {
     foreach(var item in teams)
     Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
    }

    public void TeamSearch()
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter the team you wish to search for: ");
     string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
     if (teams.Contains(userinput))
     Console.WriteLine("Success, team " + userinput);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a team you wish to delete: ");
      string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
      teams.Remove(userinput);
      foreach (var item in teams)
      Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
    }
```

I know I have worded this poorly, so I hope that someone understands what I'm asking :P

Answer (score 23):

You can use a do while loop for the purpose
Make a little modification to your DispalyMenu() method and return the result like this

```
static public int DisplayMenu()
{   
  Console.WriteLine("Football Manager");
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Football team");
  Console.WriteLine("2. List the Football teams");
  Console.WriteLine("3. Search for a Football team");
  Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a team");
  Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
  var result = Console.ReadLine();
  return Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

and write this in your Main() method

```
int userInput = 0;
do
{
  userInput = DisplayMenu();
}while(userInput!=5);
```

So for the time being the user does not enter '5', the code will execute in the loop.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Great example. One small comment: int.TryParse(result,out item) might be a better because it won't throw an exception if a non integer is entered.

Answer (score 14):

See [`Console.ReadKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadKey).

Replace your main function with:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    FootballTeams MyCode = new FootballTeams();

    MyCode.ListInit();

    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

    do {
        MyCode.DisplayMenu();
        cki = Console.ReadKey(false); // show the key as you read it
        switch (cki.KeyChar.ToString()) {
            case "1":
                MyCode.AddTeams();
                break;
            case "2":
                MyCode.DisplayTeams();
                break;
            // etc..
        }
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

}
```

Essentially, you need to loop until they press the Escape key.  Each time you read the key, you can execute the action selected.

Comment: When I actually run it none of the methods work, so say I press 1 to add a team, instead of initializing that method it just prints the menu?

Comment: The methods you've shown don't actually do anything.  Therefore when you select an option nothing is executed and the break is then executed and the menu is then reprinted.

Comment: The boolean in ReadKey is to intercept the key not display it.  To display it, the boolean should be false

Comment: @tinstaafl I took the contents of the methods out to shorten the post, I will add them back in

Comment: @user2852418: See update.  The case statements should have been looking for `D1` and `D2` instead of `1` and `2`.  Also, you need to remove the `ReadLine` statement from your `.DisplayMenu()` method.  I tested locally and it works fine.

Comment: Using .Key means you have to allow for both sets of number keys.  If you use .KeyChar then the case would be Case "1"c and it wouldn't matter which number key was pressed.

Comment: @tinstaafl: Right you are.

Answer (score 11):

There is a nuget package for this now

https://github.com/splttingatms/EasyConsole

Example

After adding the nuget package the Menu can be implemented the following way, This is a very Basic option

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var menu = new EasyConsole.Menu()
      .Add("foo", () => Console.WriteLine("foo selected"))
      .Add("bar", () => Console.WriteLine("bar selected"));
    menu.Display();
}
```

In the action you can place Any Method to run when selected

This will output something like this

1. foo
2. bar

Choose an option: